# Is this action script correct

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a action script from a decompile flash like this

```
    public function getResourceAsByteArray(resID:int):flash.utils.ByteArray
    {
        var tempByteArray:*=null;
        var fName:*=this.clazzName;
        var resDataDup:*=new clazzByteArray() as flash.utils.ByteArray;
        var resPos:*=this.post;
        var resLength:*=1024;
        var resultByteArray:*=new flash.utils.ByteArray();
        resDataDup.position = resPos;
        resDataDup.readBytes(resultByteArray, 0, resLength);
        return resultByteArray;
    }

    public class clazzByteArray extends mx.core.ByteArrayAsset
    {
        public function clazzByteArray()
        {
            super();
            return;
        }
    }
```

I'm not a action script programmer, but I try to understand this function.
`resDataDup` is a local object from a class that extends `ByteArray`, and I think with this initialize way `resDataDup` will always empty, so the next readBytes call always fail. Is there a chance it can work in other way? (some one can put data to `resDataDup` before readBytes is called), or the decompiler did not generate it correct.

Comment: Why don't you contact the guy you are stealing the code from and ask him

Comment: A little benefit of the doubt here would be fine, there are lots of legitimate reasons for decompiling. No reason to assume this is stolen code.

Comment: @Tyler You didn't answer @The_asMan's question

Comment: What question? I'm not the guy who asked the original question, I'm just saying there is no reason to automatically assume the original poster stole the code in question.

Comment: @The_asMan: this is from an old project, and he had gone away. I know that this kind of question will lead to say that stealing code, but I have my reason to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely correct. This code will not work. I suspect that what your decompiler is not telling you is that ByteArrayAssets are primarily for [embedded assets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ByteArrayAsset.html) in Flex. This means that `clazzByteArray` is actually referencing some *thing* which used to be embedded. But, that does not help here.

Comment: I've found other incorrect of de-compiler, maybe above is too.

Answer (score 1):

The decompiler is wrong. As @cwallenpoole said, that ByteArray was most likely an asset embedded with mxmlc (Flex SDK Compiler) rather than the Flash IDE, which uses a different mechanism.

There are however decompilers, that can handle Flex projects, such as the Sothink Decompiler. If you're already using it, maybe you'll have more luck if you tell it to decompile the SWF to a Flex project rather than an .fla.